# Which programming language works with tables and databases, considering reports and GUI?

Tags: python, javascript, c++, microsoft-excel, vba

I’ve been working with VBA previously but i want to learn other programming language, having a project in place I would like to know which language to pick and start learning…
This project is based in some in some tables and database, working with importing tables, result recording, creating reports…

Thanks folks!

Comment: Browser based, or desktop app?

Comment: Hi @Mawg, ideally desktop app